# Is there a way to find/closely estimate the value that the Mean Value Theorem promises?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, mean-value-theorem

For background, the Mean Value Theorem says that if $f\in C^1([a,b])$, then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}.$$

My question is, how does $c$ vary as a function of properties of $f$, $a$, and $b$?

For some $f$, we have an easy closed form for $c$.  Take $f(x) = x^3$, $a = 0$, and $b$ an arbitrary $x$ (wlog, assume $x > 0$), for example.  Then we have the equation

$$\frac{x^3}{x} = 3c^2,$$

so that $c = \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$.

But what if the function is more complicated?
Obviously we could just solve numerically, but is there a theorem that can tell us anything interesting about $c$?  For example, a theorem that tells us when $c$ is a polynomial function of $x$?  Or an algebraic function?  Or how close to $x / 2$ we can expect $c$ to be?  How good an estimate $c = x/2$ is?  How higher derivatives affect whether $c$ is closer to one or the other endpoint?  Etc.

**Running list of insights**

- We may assume $a = 0$ and $f(0) = 0$ without loss of generality because derivatives are well-defined up to addition by a constant and phase shifts do not affect the underlying problem.

Comment: The $c$ is a turning point of a certain function, obtained via Rouché’s theorem - see the proof of the MVT on Wikipedia

Comment: So is the question: "What is $c$ in terms of $f, a$ and $b?$"

Comment: @AdamRubinson That's the essence, but the question is a little more general.

Comment: @FShrike Do you mean Rolle's Theorem rather than Rouché's?  If so, the proof is clear but not constructive.

Comment: Whoops, I did indeed mean Rolle

Comment: This has nothing to do with convex analysis.

Comment: @copper.hat So nothing whatsoever from convex analysis could be the least helpful, even though that field is, in part, the study of functions with a non-trivial relationship to their secant lines?

Comment: @mr_e_man Yeah, poor choice of words with "closed form" on my part.  After all, in general there is a closed form $c = (f')^{-1}\Big(\frac{f(x)}{x}\Big)$ assuming $f(0) = 0$ wlog.  But this isn't necessarily an easy function to compute or describe by hand, so my other questions remain.  Will reword the question.

Comment: @DaveMoutardier Nothing that I am aware of. Without additional assumptions it seems unlikely that some relationship exists. For example, the set of such $c$s could be infinite.